# If statement in R

Tags: r, if-statement

I am unable to do an IF comparison of objects. When I compare them with numeric values the IF works, e.g.: `if (c1 < c2){do something}` fails `if (c1 < 0 ){do something}` works.

This is the code I am working with which is showing errors, where `HighValues` is a list of numbers and `LowValue` is a list of numbers as well. Is the comparison I am doing wrong?

```
checkHS<-function(HighValues,LowValues)
{
  counter<-1
  patternList<-c()

  while(counter < length(HighValues))
  {
     cmpValue1<- 0.15*HighValues[[counter]]
     cmpValue2<- HighValues[[counter+1]]
     if(cmpValue1<cmpValue2) 
     patternList<-c(patternList,counter)
     counter<-counter+1

  }
  return (patternList)
}
```

What am I doing wrong?

Edit: Adding a data set that i am passing to the function for more clarity.

`HighValues<-c(1:100)`

LowValues<-c(2:101)

Comment: What is the type of the HighValues object?  Why are you passing LowValues at all?  Do you want counter to increment conditionally or every time?  It's very unclear code... in terms of intent.  BTW, your example lines should work fine... what do you mean by "doesn't work"?  If you set c1 and c2 to something the lines do what they're supposed to do.  Once you clear this up better you should get some good response with R code that doesn't look anything like what you have.  The way you're doing it is very inefficient and un-R-like.

Comment: HighValues Object is of type of list , the counter increment everytime irrespective of the condition , the LowValues is for a second If condition which i have not added here , the above code generates** True/False not found Error** . I did try to set c1 and c2 but its just not working. I am still wondering why.

Comment: Can you post a small example of the type of data you pass to the function?

Comment: @JoshO'Brien - I have added the data set . Please do check.

Comment: FYI, that HighValues and LowValues data you added are vectors, not lists.  I asked because you're indexing like they're lists which suggests that all of the data might not be of the same type.  If it's just numbers and a list make it a vector first (`unlist()` it) so that you can be sure that you're working with the proper data type.

Comment: Thanks @John , will do the needful.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

When I run the function with the data you've supplied, it evaluates to completion without complaint, returning just the values it should:

```
head(checkHS(HighValues=HighValues, LowValues=LowValues))
[1] 1 2 3 4 5 6
```

That said, the following code does the same thing as the function you've posted. It takes advantage of R's ability to 'vectorize' calculations, resulting in code that's more expressive and easier to read.

```
checkHS2 <- function(HighValues,LowValues) {
    cmpValue1 <- 0.15*HighValues[-length(HighValues)]
    cmpValue2 <- HighValues[-1]
    which(cmpValue1 < cmpValue2)
}
```

Comment: Thanks man , figured a way out , dint use which but definitely the use of logic made it clear.

Thanks again.

Answer (score -2):

the key to answer your question is: "What are you expecting as result?"

When I ran your code, I have not found any error inside it, function is returning values.

Comment: It returned true/false expected.